# Uniform edge paths throughout the tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

How do I achieve uniform edge paths throughout the tree, the one similar to the path from root to the immediate children? That is to have sharp corners instead of curved corners here. Also what's the best way to separate each level's sibling distance and level distance?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    edge from parent/.style={-latex,solid,black,thick,sloped,draw},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west);},
    edge from parent fork down
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
basic/.style = {draw, text width=5cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
root/.style = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=white},
level 1/.style={},
level 2/.style={basic,rounded corners=4pt, thin,align=center, fill=white, text width=3cm},
level 3/.style={basic,rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=white, text width=2cm},
level 4/.style={basic,rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=white, text width=2cm,sibling distance=10em, level distance=10em}
]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node[root] {\textbf{Root}} [sibling distance=25em, level distance=8em]
% The first level, as children of the initial tree
    child {node[level 2] (c1) {\textbf{Child 1l}} [sibling distance=10em, level distance=6em]
        child {node [level 3] (c11) {Granchild 1-1} [sibling distance=10em, level distance=7em]
            child {node [level 4] (c111) {Dummy text}}}
        child {node [level 3] (c12) {Granchild 1-2} [sibling distance=10em, level distance=7em]
            child{node [level 4] (c121) {{Dummy text}}}
        }
        child {node [level 3] (c13) {Granchild 1-3} [sibling distance=10em, level distance=7em]
            child{node [level 4] (c131) {{Dummy text}}}
        }
    }
    child {node[level 2] (c2) {\textbf{Child 2}} [sibling distance=10em, level distance=6em]
        child {node [level 3] (c21) {Grandchild 2-1} [sibling distance=10em, level distance=7em]
            child {node [level 4] (c211) {{Dummy text}}}
        }
        child {node [level 3] (c22) {Grandchild 2-2} [sibling distance=10em, level distance=7em]
            child {node [level 4] (c221) {{Dummy text}}}
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a simple Taxonomy}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: Add `sharp corners` to `edge from parent/.style={-latex,solid,black,thick,sloped,draw},` ? (Not sure what `sloped` is good for here, it should not have any effect.)

Comment: It seems that your edges inherit the `rounded corners` from your levels styles. Like @ABC said, adding a `sharp corners` option to your `edge from parent` style should be enough.